# If $G$ is a connected graph, then $G$ contains an Euler circuit if and only if every vertex has even degree (Misunderstanding of terminology).

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I believe that I must be misunderstanding some of the terminology here. To my understanding, the included image is a connected graph where $\{ v_1,e_1,v_2,e_2,v_3,e_3,v_1 \}$ is contained within $G,$ and a Euler Circuit. Yet, $v_4$ clearly has degree one, which is odd. This is in contradiction with the Theorem, I believe I'm simply misunderstanding a definition, but I can't conclude what it is.[image]

Comment: I think the confusion is in the use of the word "contains." The way you've interpreted things, any graph will contain an Eulerian Circuit if it has a loop, i.e. is not a tree. A more clear statement would be that a graph admits an Eulerian Circuit if and only if each vertex has even degree.

Comment: I would not use *contains*; the usual idiom is that a graph *has* an Euler circuit, and that means that there is an Euler circuit that includes all of its edges.

Comment: Thank you both! Brian, this cleared up my confusion. I felt like there was a bit of ambiguity whenever I was reading the statement of the Theorem, I guess my intuition about that was correct. 

I appreciate the clarification.